# multilingual autosuggestion using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

I'm doing project in vb.net which has multilingual facility.in which one form contain textbox have autosuggestion facility,if i select language marathi at the time of login then the autosuggetsion want to work in marathi for this perticular txtbox. I'm using following code.  Then What Code I write for autosuggestion then the dropdown autosuggestion list will disply in marathi language

```
Public Sub bindCastType()
    ' Me.txtSearchValue.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    Dim objDs As New DataSet
    Dim Cast As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim objcast As CastManager = New CastManager
    objDs = objcast.GetCastInfoByQuery("", "")

    If Not objDs.Tables(0) Is Nothing Then
        If objDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In objDs.Tables(0).Rows
                Cast.Add(row.Item(1))
            Next
        End If
    End If

    txtCastID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

    txtCastID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

    txtCastID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Cast
End Sub
```

MY Question is: What Code I write for autosuggestion then the dropdown autosuggestion list will disply in marathi language

Comment: What Code I write for autosuggestion then the dropdown autosuggestion list will disply in marathi language

Answer (score 0):

You add a language-id parameter to your query:

```
objDs = objcast.GetCastInfoByQuery("", "",LanguageID)
```

so it only select rows for the selected language.